# How to disable "New instance of microsoft Visual Studio" in JIT debugger in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

When my C# application launches the JIT, the the first option is "New instance of Microsoft Visual Studio" and the second one is the actual instance of VS that I have painstakingly prepared and I want to use.

Most of the time I double click on my instance, but sometimes I hit "New..." and I have to close it and start again.

So is there any way to get rid of that "New instance..." option? It should either use the existing VS instance or nothing. If possible.

Comment: Thanks Brian, but I think that's not what I am looking for, and that's because I did not explain myself clearly.
I need the JIT. When I start the code (it's a Windows service) that was built in Debug, it's popping up a window saying "An unhandled Microsoft .NET Framework exception occurred in..." and then it says "Possible Debuggers:". 
In this list of possible debuggers, the first one is always "New Instance of Microsoft Visual Studio 2010". The second option is another instance, that I have prepared for debug.
I don't want to see that first option, New Instance.

Comment: See image
http://i42.tinypic.com/6i9shx.jpg

Answer (score 1):

1. On the Tools menu, click Options.
2. In the Options dialog box, select the Debugging folder.
3. In the Debugging folder, select the Just-In-Time page.
4. In the Enable Just-In-Time debugging of these types of code box, select or clear the relevant program types: Managed, Native, or Script.
   **NOTE:**  To disable Just-In-Time debugging, once it has been enabled, you must be running with Administrator privileges. Enabling Just-In-Time debugging sets a registry key, and Administrator privileges are required to change that key.
5. Click OK

Comment: To Whom It May Concern:  Thank you for the down vote without a related comment.  You are the downfall of social web sites.

Comment: I am learning VS right now and this answer helped with an issue I was having, +1.  Thanks!